# OrderBy timestamp desc Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently working with firestore, I'm implementing a review service, where a customer can score and comment about a course, I'm trying to retrieve the reviews by timestamp in descending order, but the snapshot is empty, but when I retrieve the reviews in ascending order, the snapshot comes with results. I filter the reviews to match a given course and ensure the comments are not banned for bad language. So in the end, I have a query like this.

```
firestore
  .collection("reviews")
  .where("course", "==", this.course.id)
  .where("censored", "==", false)
  .orderBy("timestamp", "desc") 
  .startAfter(this.pagination)
  .limit(5)
  .get()
```

The collection that I'm querying is the reviews collections, a review contains the following properties

```
{
 // If a review was censored
 censored: boolean,
 // The comment of the review
 comment: string,
 // The score of the review from O to 5
 score: number,
 // The course uid that is being reviewed
 course: string,
 // The timestamp when the review was created
 timestamp: timestamp, (time mark)
 // The user that review the course
 user: {
  email: string,
  name: string,
  id: string,
 }
}
```

I'm expecting to get as result the comment ordered in a descending way, to see the comment from the latest to the oldesd. But the query only comes with results when is ordered in an ascending way. There is no error in the query, in only comes with `empty: true` and `size: 0`.

The ascending and the descending indexes are created.

The ascending index
`censored Ascendente course Ascendente timestamp Ascendente`

The descending index
`censored Ascendente course Ascendente timestamp Descendente`

I already tried a solution by changing the `.get` for a `.onSnapshot`, but I didn't work.

Comment: Are you getting any error? Please share what is not working. It can throw some light. Also, what is the data type of `timestamp` - is it `string` or `number`?

Comment: Timestamp is a firestore timestamp value, and no, It just comes with any result If I query by descending order.

Comment: What is the field name used to store the firestore `timestamp` value? Please check if the field name is exactly `timestamp` them the query should work.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the data that you expect to be returned from this query, and be sure to also show the values of the variables you use here.  We can't see your database, and we can't see your variables, so there's not much we can do.  Your question should contain enough information that anyone can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @DougStevenson I made an edit I hope it contain enough information.

Comment: Hey, I believe that in this case, it would be better to open a case with support, as I believe they could check this better, I tried to replicate this myself but, no luck so far, Maybe you could try with a new collection and other fields (much simpler collection, maybe just name and age, and order by age, to check out if it is an error connected to a specific connection or field. I tried a structure like that... and it is working)

Comment: You can contact them at this [link](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact)

Comment: Having the same issue. I get results for ascending using 'asc' but not for descending using 'desc' as described. Funny thing is I have created an index for only descending but it always returns only ascending and none for descending.